# Can a distributed system designed with logical clocks truly derive a total ordering of events?

Tags: distributed-system

I’m reading Leslie Lamport’s white paper, “[Time, clocks, and the ordering of events in a distributed system](https://amturing.acm.org/p558-lamport.pdf)”. His explanation for total ordering has me a bit confused in the following excerpt.

[image]

1. I've interpreted this as if event x's timestamp is less than event y
   then x happened before y.
2. If x's timestamp is the same as y's
   timestamp then use the process name to determine who comes first.

I'm confused because if x is less than y then there are two possibilities to my understanding; either x happened first or x and y are concurrent. It seems like he's always assuming the former and never the latter.

Comment: This question might have better luck on the Software Engineering StackExchange, but how I'm reading it is "if the timestamps are the same (happening concurrently), we just need to have a standard system for deciding how to order the events." Later (about half a page below your screenshot) he says "[The condition that] different requests for the resource must be granted in the order in which they are made [...] says nothing about which of two concurrently issued requests should be granted first."

Comment: I'm more concerned with the total ordering aspect rather than the mutual exclusion part. His definition of concurrent events is related to causality; two events can occur at different temporal times but still be considered concurrent so long as they don't causally affect each other. This is why #1 is throwing me off.

Comment: Please [edit] to add transcriptions of your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Comment: If x is less than y, why does it matter whether or not x and y are concurrent?  X happened before y.  Period.

Comment: It matters because these are Lamport timestamps; their values are assigned by a logical clock and not a temporal one. If they're concurrent then their timestamps do no provide any insight in their ordering so it seems impossible to create a total ordering.

Answer (score 1):

As a clarification: "A happened before B" means that result of A influenced B in some way. If A did not happen before B, then two events are concurrent - B is not influenced by A in any way - (not as wall time concurrent, but from causality point of view).

Two notes:

> I've interpreted this as if event x's timestamp is less than event y then x happened before y.

Lamport timestamp does not capture causality. When X < Y, the only thing we can be sure about is that Y did no happened before X. We can't conclude if X happened before Y or they are concurrent. This is by definition of Total Order. To detect concurrent events, you would need to use Vector clock.

> I'm confused because if x is less than y then there are two possibilities to my understanding; either x happened first or x and y are concurrent. It seems like he's always assuming the former and never the latter.

Technically you are right - for any two events they are either concurrent or one happened before the other. But we don't assume anything - we know that we won't be able to decide on this by using Total Order.

Edit: from your comment - " If they're concurrent then their timestamps do no provide any insight in their ordering so it seems impossible to create a total ordering."

I am not sure how you arrived to this statement. You actually create total order by throwing away the information about concurrency, that's the spirit of Lamport timestamp algorithm.

If we have:

- event A happened before B
- A happened before C
- B happened before D
- C happened before D

then we know that A happened before D. Applying Lamport timestamp algorithm will give us total order: ABCD or ACBD. While B and C are truly concurrent (neither happened before the other), they still will have different position in total order - even if we don't know which one will come first.

From another point of view - let's say we have a distributed system producing events. Using Lamport timestamp we will be able to get some total order. If we will send this total order to another distributed system for a replay of all events - the new system won't be able to decide on concurrency and will have to execute events one by one according to the total order.